# Question about an inequality.

Tags: inequality, natural-numbers

$$\forall i\in \{1,2,\cdots, k\}, n_i\in\mathbb{N}$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^k n_i =n$$
then
$$\sum_{i=1}^k n_i^2\leq n^2-(k-1)(2n-k)$$

---

Like comment, If we apply induction,

$i)\ k=2$

$n_1+n_2=n\land n_1,n_2\in \mathbb{N}$

then
$$n_1^2+n_2^2=n_1^2+(n-n_1)^2=n^2-2n_1n+2n_1^2=2(n_1-\frac{n}{2})^2+\frac{n^2}{2}$$

Actually this have maximum if $|n_1-\frac{n}{2}|$ is maximum(when $n_1=1 \lor n_1=n-1$)
therefore $$n_1^2+n_2^2\leq 1^2+(n-1)^2= n^2-1*(2n-2)$$

ii)for induction,

suppose $\sum_{i=1}^k n_i=n\land n_i\in \mathbb{N}$ 
imply
$$\sum_{i=1}^k n_i^2\leq n^2-(k-1)(2n-k)$$

and

claim:$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} n_i=n\land n_i\in \mathbb{N}$
 imply
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} n_i^2\leq n^2-k(2n-k-1)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} n_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^k n_i^2+n_{k+1}^2\leq  (n-n_{k+1})^2-(k-1)(2n-2n_{k+1}-k)+n_{k+1}^2$$
$$=2n_{k+1}^2-2n_{k+1}(n-k+1)+n^2-2n(k-1)+k(k-1)$$
$$=2(n_{k+1}-\frac{n-k+1}{2})^2-\frac{(n-k+1)^2}{2}+n^2-2n(k-1)+k(k-1)$$

Actually It have maximum if $|n_{k+1}-\frac{n-k+1}{2}|$ is maximum, (at $n_{k+1}=1\lor n-k$) therefore
$$\leq \frac{(n-k-1)^2}{2}-\frac{(n-k+1)}{2}+n^2-2n(k-1)+k(k-1)$$
$$=-2(n-k)+n^2-2n(k-1)+(k-1)k$$
$$=n^2-k(2n-k-1)$$

therefore
$$\sum_{i=1}^k n_i^2\leq n^2-(k-1)(2n-k)$$ and equality occur when $\forall i= 1,2,\cdots,k-1 ,n_i=1,n_k=n-k+1$

Comment: Induction looks like a useful starting point. I'm not going to guarantee it'll work, though, but it would be my instinct with things like these. If you could provide details on an approach you've tried, it might be more helpful.

Comment: It's false: for $n_1=n_2=0$ and $n_3=2$ we have $0^2+0^2+2^2\leq 2^2-(3-1)(2\cdot 2-3)$ which is false.

Comment: $n_1,n_2,n_3\in \mathbb{N}$ so $n_1,n_2,n_3\geq 1$

Answer (score 1):

Let $m = \min n_i$ and $M = \max n_i$. We are told $n_i \ge 1$ (i.e. $\mathbb{N}$ stands for the set of positive integers), so $m \ge 1$ and hence
$$M \le n - (k-1)m \le n - k + 1$$

This leads to

$$\begin{align}
\sum_i n_i^2 &= \sum_i ((n_i+1)(n_i-1) + 1)
\le (M+1)\sum_i (n_i - 1) + k\\
&\le (n - k + 2)(n-k) + k
= n^2 - (k-1)(2n-k)
\end{align}\tag{*1}
$$
This is the inequality we want to prove. We can improve this inequality by
using the actual maximum $M$ and minimum $m$. We have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_i n_i^2 &= \sum_i ((n_i+m)(n_i-m) + m^2)
\le (M+m)\sum_i (n_i - m) + km^2\\
&\le (M+m)(n - km) + km^2
= (M+m)n - kMm
\end{align}
$$
Let $\mu = \frac{n}{k}$ and $\sigma$ be the mean and standard derivation of $n_i$. Above inequality is equivalent to

$$k (\sigma^2 + \mu^2) \le (M+m)\mu k - kMm
\quad\iff\quad \sigma^2 \le (M - \mu)(\mu - m)\tag{*2}$$

When we replace $M$ and $m$ by other upper/lower bounds for $n_i$, $(M - \mu)(\mu - m)$ will only getting bigger and inequality $(*2)$ remains valid.
The inequality $(*1)$ is really a special case of this when we replace $M, m$ by  $n-k+1$ and $1$.

The inequality on RHS$(*2)$ is known as [Bhatia–Davis inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhatia%E2%80%93Davis_inequality). Look at its wiki entry for similar bounds.